# Can't use geolocation on Windows

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, windows-10-universal

I have an Ionic 2 app which is working fine on Android & IOS. I am now trying to build for Windows and the app is working fine other than I can't use the geolocation features.

I have taken the following steps:

1. `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation --save`
2. `ionic platform add windows`
3. `ionic build windows`
4. Installed the app on a Lumia 650 by using the green `Debug` button in VS2015.

I then use this function to get the geolocation:

```
getUserGeolocation() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition({
        timeout: 5000,
        enableHighAccuracy: true
      }).then(
        (res) => {
          resolve(res.coords);
        },
        (err) => {
          reject(err);
        }
      );
    });
}
```

On Windows, this results in an error 'Geolocation access has not been allowed by user.'.

I have gone into the phone settings and checked `Privacy > Location`. Everything is enabled in here but my app doesn't show in the list of `Choose apps that can use your precise location`. Not sure if this is normal or not.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks for any help.

**Edit**

Forgot to say that `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~2.4.1"/>` is in `config.xml` and the plugins in my `package.json` look like this:

```
"cordovaPlugins": [
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-badge",
    "cordova-plugin-app-event",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation",
    "cordova-plugin-compat",
    "cordova-plugin-globalization",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information"
  ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added the [`location`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#device-capabilities) capability to your `AppXManifest.xml` file? See [How to specify capabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br211477) for more info.

Also note that if your app targets Windows 10 [you need to call `RequestAccessAsync` before you make any calls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.aspx) and I'm not sure if ionic has been updated to do that.

Comment: I added `<DeviceCapability Name="location" />` into the `package.windows10.appxmanifest` file and it works now. Thanks very much!